# Как изменить сортировку элементов по умолчанию для Yii2 responsive filemanager?

Tags: php, yii2, tinymce

Добрый день.В конфигурационном файле config.php не нашел возможности изменить тип сортировки на сортировку по дате, начиная с последних изменений, в доках информации тоже не было. Кто нибудь сталкивался ? Пакет: https://github.com/xvs32x/tinymce-responsivefilemanager

Comment: Доброе утро. Какой именно пакет Вы используете?

Comment: Ссылку на пакет, закрепил выше

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но глянув на исходники нашёл только в файле assets/filemanager/dialog.php на строке 175

Comment: Попробуйте изменить, может и поможет

Comment: Но при обновлении пакета Ваши изменения затрутся. Видать не предусмотрена возможность изменить сортировку.

Comment: Спасибо большое Борис. Вы правы. В данном случае пакет не планирую обновлять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поступил следующим образом для сортировки по дате, начиная с последних:

```
  $_SESSION['RF']['sort_by'] = 'date';
```

и 192 строка:

```
 $descending = $_SESSION['RF']['descending'] = fix_get_params($_GET["descending"])==0;
```